# Submitting a form with mechanize (TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence)

Tags: python, mechanize-python

I'm trying to submit a form with mechanize but have run into an error (TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence) After googling for some time and trying a couple of different solutions I haven't been able to solve the issue. I'm trying to submit all the fields.

The form data fetched via mechanize (for f in br.forms() print: f)

```
<POST http://www.example.com/takeupload.php multipart/form-data
<HiddenControl(MAX_FILE_SIZE=1000000) (readonly)>
<TextControl(<None>=http://www.example.com:81/test.php?pass=550) (readonly)>
<FileControl(file=<No files added>)>
<TextControl(name=)>
<SelectControl(type=[*0, 23, 22, 1, 10, 7, 18, 4, 21, 56, 20, 60, 5, 19, 6, 55, 63, 9])>
<CheckboxControl(strip=[strip])>
<FileControl(nfo=<No files added>)>
<TextareaControl(descr=)>
<SubmitControl(<None>=Do it!) (readonly)>>
```

My current code

```
br.open('http://www.bitfarm.co.za/upload.php')

br.select_form(nr=4)

filename = 'test.torrent'
br.form.add_file(open(filename), 'application/x-bittorrent', filename, name='file') 
br.form['name'] = 'test'
br.form['type'] = '22'
br.form['strip'] = '0'
br.form['nfo'] = ''
br.form['descr'] = 'This is the desc'

br.submit()
```

Please could you assist and check I'm using the right syntax for the form options. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`type` field expects a list of integers from you, but you provide just one integer.
Change this:

```
br.form['type'] = '22'
```

to this:

```
br.form['type'] = ['22',]
```

Comment: @Michael, I have to double check by myself, so it will be much faster, if you just run your code and see whether it works yourself.

Comment: Thanks it does work, kinda. One has error. The br.form['descr'] is giving an 

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file C:\Python\login.py on line 79, b
ut no encoding declared

How do I set encoding to be correct? Thanks

Comment: @Michael, the only suggestion I can make without seeing your file, is - read this: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/