# How to make a list in Python that ends with a trailing comma?

Tags: python, list, mechanize

When using mechanize to change the state of an item in a form, I need to make a list in Python like this one:

```
['2009', '2008', '2007', '2006', '2005', '2004',]
```

The list must end with the trailing comma, or else it won't work. For instance, the following code works:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['ctl03'] = ['2009', '2008', '2007',]
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['ctl03'] = ['2009', '2008', '2007']
```

---

this is the error message I get when I don't use the trailing comma:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Renato/PycharmProjects/Agrolink/faostat.py", line 43, in <module>
    br['ctl03$DesktopThreePanes1$ThreePanes$ctl01$TMyears'] = ['2009', '2008', '2007']
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 2782, in __setitem__
    control.value = value
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 1977, in __setattr__
    self._set_value(value)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_form.py", line 1985, in _set_value
    raise TypeError("ListControl, must set a sequence")
TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence
Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

Well, after dealing with this problem for an entire afternoon, I learned that this is how I  could get it to do what I needed WITHOUT the trailing comma:

```
 mylist = ['2009', '2008', '2007']
 br.set_value(mylist, name="ctl03")
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean?  Do you mean you'd like to print a list with a trailing comma or do you mean you'd like to assign a variable from a list with a trailing comma?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?  There is no reason to end a list with a comma...

Comment: Searching for TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence will show that this question has been asked a number of times; however there is no solution other than to type the list myself.

Comment: Is there anyway you could run a debugger on this application? Specifically i would like to know what the value of value at line  1984 (one before the exception is).  "if value is None or isstringlike(value)" Which is tripping this call? isstringlike or None?

Comment: @relima Check my answer - I have updated using `dis` to disassemble the Python bytecode for constructing the lists with and without the extra comma, and they are exactly the same - hence cannot be the factor that matters here.

Comment: If you attempt to use mechanize, you will see that

br['ctl03'] = ['2009', '2008', '2007',]

and 

br['ctl03'] = ['2009', '2008', '2007']

produce 2 very different results: one works, the other doesnt.

Still, I solved the problem by using br.set_value(mylist) .

Comment: @relima Can you give a link to a page that shows this behaviour?

Comment: @relima I can not reproduce this behaviour - see the test case in my answer.

Comment: Let me finish doing this job and then I will send you my code through pastebin. Now I am really curious as to why the trailing comma makes such a difference in my code.

Comment: @Lattyware, the following question also relates to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161764/submitting-a-form-with-mechanize-typeerror-listcontrol-must-set-a-sequence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense - the comma is a formatting thing put in when representing the list as a string, the comma holds no value to the list itself.

Do you want to change the output of the list as a string, or do something else here? If you want to have an extra 'empty' item, then you could append `None` to the list, for example, to emulate that.

To make a string formatted with an extra comma like that, you will want to do something like this:

```
"["+", ".join(mylist)+",]"
```

Update for your edit:

The two lines you have listed mean the exact same thing in Python - there is no way that one works and the other doesn't. The trailing comma is syntactic sugar that allows you to be lazy about writing out list literals.

```
>>> ['2009', '2008', '2007',] == ['2009', '2008', '2007']
True
```

Edit again:

It's an actual impossibility that the trailing comma affects your code. If we disassemble the byte-code python produces:

```
import dis

def test1():
    ['2009', '2008', '2007',]

def test2():
    ['2009', '2008', '2007']

dis.dis(test1)
dis.dis(test2)
```

Which gives us:

```
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('2009') 
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('2008') 
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('2007') 
              9 BUILD_LIST               3 
             12 POP_TOP              
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             16 RETURN_VALUE         
  7           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('2009') 
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('2008') 
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('2007') 
              9 BUILD_LIST               3 
             12 POP_TOP              
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can see the byte code is exactly the same. The extra comma is not stored as information with the list. Given this, we can say that this is not what is affecting your code, so could you simplify your example to something we can test, with a reproducible error, we can see what the problem actually is.

I cannot reproduce this behaviour:

test.html:

```
<form name="test">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" /> I have a bike<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" /> I have a car
</form>
```

And then:

```
>>> br.open("file:///path/to/test.html")
<response_seek_wrapper at 0x1d74cf8 whose wrapped object = <closeable_response at 0x1f9be60 whose fp = <open file '/path/to/test.html', mode 'rb' at 0x221b9c0>>>
>>> br.select_form(name="test")
>>> br["vehicle"] = ["Bike", "Car",]
>>> br["vehicle"] = ["Bike", "Car"]
```

Both variants work without complaint.

Comment: ... sorry, what? What in my answer solved your problem? I mean, I'm glad it did, but it was intended to show you your question had a flawed premise.

Comment: Actually, you are right, it dint fix the problem. I am changing the question to show the error message.

Comment: Thanks for trying really hard to reproduce my error, I updated the question to reflect what I did to fix the problem, though. I don´t know if this may be behind the error, but in my form I using input type="hidden" . Still, br.set_value does what I need without the need to use the trailling comma.

Comment: @relima I tested with an input of type `hidden` and I got an error unless I assigned a string - no lists were allowed at all.

Comment: try using br.form.set_all_readonly(False) before doing the change.

Comment: @relima No change. I also tried using a `select` element, which worked perfectly with or without the comma.