# Error 403: Request disallowed by robots.txt on Python

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to fill a form using mechanize on python. When I run the code, I get an error:

> Error 403:request disallowed by robots.txt.

I went through the previous answered questions with similar issue and saw that adding `br.set_handle_robots(False)` should fix it, but I am still getting the same error. So what am I missing here?

```
import re
import mechanize
from mechanize import Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 (compatible;)'),('Accept', '*/*')]
text = "1500103233"
browser = Browser()
browser.open("http://kuhs.ac.in/results.htm")
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser['Stream']=['Medical']
browser['Level']=['UG']
browser['Course']=['MBBS']
browser['Scheme']=['MBBS 2015 Admissions']
browser['Year']=['Ist Year MBBS']
browser['Examination']=['First Professional MBBS Degree Regular(2015 Admissions) Examinations,August2016']
browser['Reg No']=text
response = browser.submit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You set `br = mechanize.Browser()` and then you set `browser = Browser()` ?
2. The link : `http://kuhs.ac.in/results.htm` if you can see from the page source, the source is : `src="http://14.139.185.148/kms/index.php/results/create"`
3. From the page source you can see the name of forms. In your case `Stream</label` is `name="Results[streamId]"`

So , you can try this :

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 (compatible;)'),('Accept', '*/*')]
text = "1500103233"
br.open("http://14.139.185.148/kms/index.php/results/create").read()
for forms in br.forms():
    print forms
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['Results[streamId]']=['1',] #Medical
#etc..
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

You can see here :[Submitting a form with mechanize (TypeError: ListControl, must set a sequence)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161764/submitting-a-form-with-mechanize-typeerror-listcontrol-must-set-a-sequence)

Hope this helps, it works for me!